# Slick slider not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get bootstrap working with slick slider. If I remove bootstrap cdn slick slider works ok but when I add it back it stops working. idk what's wrong. Here's the code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fade">
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.fade').slick({
                    dots: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 700,
                    autoplay:true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                    arrows:false,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After removing the bootstrap cdn file it works fine. I have also tried bootstrap 4, got same result.

Comment: Some function that is needed in the slider script is overwritten by the bootsrap script. I guess they both need it. My dirty solution would be to place the bootstrap file first, and then test to make sure that all bootstrap functions that I'm using still work. A few functions shall be overwritten, but the chance seems reasonable that you are not using those functions anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at you `div` with `fade` class, you'll see that the `opacity` is set to `0` when `bootstrap` is loaded.

So you have to put `opacity` to `1` on this `div`.

You can do it like this:

```
div.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**EDIT** : As @OmkarVaity said in comments (thanks), `.fade` is a class in bootstrap which sets the `opacity` to `0`. To avoid messing styles, you can rename the `.fade` class and update your call to `slick`.

Here is a working snippet:

```css
div.myslider {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myslider">
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.myslider').slick({
                    dots: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 700,
                    autoplay:true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                    arrows:false,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: .fade is default class in bootstrap which has opacity :0; so use some other classname.

Comment: So, the `.fade` class used on the `div` can be renamed to avoid messing bootstrap.

Comment: yes that should you do rather than overriding in css, .fade has properties like opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap has a default class with same name "fade" . just rename it to something else .below i renamed the class 'fade' to 'fadex' and it worked fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

      

        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
        <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fadex">
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
            <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
        </div>
 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.fadex').slick({
                    dots: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 700,
                    autoplay:true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                    arrows:false,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you change from their example? Please explain why you think this solution would work and what the OP missed.

Comment: i just renamed the class name 'fade' to 'fadex'

Comment: Please add it to the answer body by editing your answer. Not everyone reads the comments and it helps the person asking learn if you explain why your answer works for their question.